# Google sign-in is not working after deploying react app on netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

I have deployed my react app on netlify everything is working as expected but google sign-in is not working in the application. Also, I have added Authorized Javascript origin and Authorized redirect URI under google console developer.

[image]

Also I tried to clear cache and cookie from the browser but i got the below error message

```
details: "Not a valid origin for the client: https://test123.netlify.app has not been registered for client ID 305573962147-ib90fi46r6ur7juhkrh6opptrvrjn722.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"
```

Is there anything I am missing over here ?

Comment: Please provide some solution if you have any.

Comment: Facing the same challenge, any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's happened to me too
you need to add the website domain to the Authorized domains
(enter this setting in desktop not mobile)

[Authorized domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trGnI.png)